# Can a college ban the use of a WiFi router for amateur radio?

Tags: united-states, amateur-radio

If a college normally bans the use of personal WiFi routers on campus, can they enforce that rule against a student who is a licensed amateur radio operator and is using the router under amateur radio regulations (Part 97; WiFi is normally Part 15)? Would PRB-1 apply in this case?

Comment: Is the radio an official college channel?

Comment: No, this is amateur radio (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio). Not radio broadcasting.

Comment: @AsheraH amateur radio WiFi is much more like regular WiFi than it is like broadcast radio; the only practical differences are that amateur radio WiFi almost always uses mesh networks, and the operators are licensed and therefore have some degree of legal right (rather than just permission) to operate the router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ARRL has a [page that explains PRB-1](http://www.arrl.org/prb-1). This FCC report and order requires local government (usually the zoning authorities) to accommodate amateur radio, especially the antennas. Nothing from the FCC gives amateur radio operators a privilege to operate amateur radio while on private property, against the wishes of the property owner.

If the college is operated by a city or state, there is a small chance they might be considered a local government for purposes of PRB-1, but one would be trying to apply the report and order to a situation that is not what PRB-1 was aimed at.